# Who is an underlicker?

Tags: meaning

I cannot find this word in any dictionary, but found a couple of examples of its use in books:

> (1) The way those **underlickers** are lounging around, they don't seem in any hurry to leave.
>
> (2) It now, therefore, struts forth like the Spanish Armada, having received the blessing of the Pope, cardinals, understrappers, and **underlickers** of the company, who have pronounced it invincible.

What is the meaning of this word?

Comment: It’s not complimentary.

Comment: Compare _under_ to _bottom_ and you have an idea of the service they provide.